# Отслеживание изменений в списке python

Tags: python, списки, словари

Python начал только-только изучать. В гугле не могу лаконично сформулировать вопрос. Возник небольшой затык. Покоряю websocket'ы и вот собственно в чём суть:
сервер хранит соединения в списке вида:

```
clients = [{'id' : id , 'addr' : (addr , port)},]
```

Необходимо отследить изменения в этом списке ( появление/удаление новых элементов в нём), и каждое изменение связать с другим списком словарей. Возможно несколько костноязычен. В общем необходимо каждое соединение, связать со списком словарей, в котором хранятся пользователи.
Вроде:

```
users = [{'uid' : uid, 'name' : 'name'},]
```

что-то вроде того. Сори если что-то не смог донести.

add

Я так предпологаю, мне надо сделать копию моего списка clients, затем по таймеру, скажем раз в 5 секунд сверять эти списки и если clients отличается от копии, перезаписывать эту копию? Это что по поводу отслеживания изменений в списке.

Comment: вэбсокет на каком сервере?

Comment: websocjet-server.  скажите хоть за что минус...

Comment: этот минус не от меня. websocjet-server - не знаю такого.. придется додумывать самому, напишу только в общих чертах

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259179/list-callbacks чтото в этом роде. но не понятно как привязывть туда users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете наследовать от списка, расширив его необходимым вам поведением:

```
from enum import Enum

class ObservalbleList(list):
    class Operations(Enum):
        APPEND = 1
        REMOVE = 2

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ObservalbleList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.callbacks = []

    def add_callback(self, f):
        self.callbacks.append(f)

    def remove_callback(self, f):
        self.callbacks.remove(f)

    def append(self, value):
        super(ObservalbleList, self).append(value)
        for callback in self.callbacks:
            callback(self.Operations.APPEND, value)

    def remove(self, value):
        super(ObservalbleList, self).remove(value)
        for callback in self.callbacks:
            callback(self.Operations.REMOVE, value)


def printer(operation, value):
    op_str = 'Добавлен' if operation == ObservalbleList.Operations.APPEND else 'Удалён'
    print(op_str + ' элемент ' + str(value))


users = ObservalbleList()
users.add_callback(printer)

users.append({'id': 1 , 'addr': ('127.0.0.1' , '1234')})
users.append({'id': 2 , 'addr': ('127.0.0.2' , '1234')})

users.remove({'id': 1 , 'addr': ('127.0.0.1' , '1234')})
```